# SQL query for Selecting from Multiple Tables in single database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I am having 3 tables (`c19` , `c19b2`, `g26`) in a database

I want to write a SQL Query to search and display all fields of the matched record.

I am using following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM c19,c19b2,g26 WHERE armyno LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";
```

But it only works for table `c19`,
Data from the other 2 tables is not fetched.Each table has a field `armyno`

Please help me with this 
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and what you would like the results to be.

Comment: It's possible that your schema design could be improved upon.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you are not looking for a `JOIN`, but a `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM c19 WHERE armyno LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM c19b2 WHERE armyno LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM g26 WHERE armyno LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
```

That will let you query all three tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Which DB are you using?  This would have worked in SQL Server.  However, notice you are doing a cross join of every record to every record... usually you only want to match some records by restriction of a matching key, for example:

```
select 
  *
from a 
left join b on b.somekey = a.somekey
left join c on c.someotherkey = b.someotherkey
```

In SQL server you can just say *, but I'm taking it that in your DB engine that didn't work, so try specifying which table.  This may in some environments require aliasing as well:

```
select 
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.*
from tableA as a 
left join tableB as b on b.somekey = a.somekey
left join tableC as c on c.someotherkey = b.someotherkey
```

Generally, you should see the columns from the first table, followed by the columns from the second table, followed by columns from the third table for a given row.  If you wanted to get all columns from all tables, but separately, then that would be 3 separate selects.

Lastly, if all 3 tables have "armyno" then I'd expect it to throw an ambiguous field error. In such case you'd want to specify which table's "armyno" field to filter on.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of 3 seperate SELECT query's :)

It worked